# Datadog metric monitor notification on Slack with link to the log explorer

Tags: logging, slack, metrics, monitor, datadog

I'm trying to setup a notification message on Slack for a monitor on a custom metric that we created. 
I would like the message to include a **timestamp** of the event, and also a link that redirect to the log, to analyze it immediately. Are there any template variable like {{var}} that let me insert the timestamp and the link to the log, or maybe that let me build the log search query string
dynamically like: 
**https://app.datadoghq.com/logs?....**
(so I will need the timestamp at least)?

At the moment we only have this in the message:

## There’s a  {{result.name}} in Registration Service

- CHANNEL: {{channel.name}}
- ENVIRONMENT: {{environment.name}}.

## Please investigate!

Answer (score 3):

In the end we solved the problem dynamically building the url for the logs:

```
https://app.datadoghq.com/logs?cols=core_host%2Ccore_service&index=&live=true&messageDisplay=inline&query=service%3Aregistration+env%3A{{environment.name}}&stream_sort=desc&to_ts={{last_triggered_at_epoch}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a 2-click path from Slack that should already do this for you out-of-the-box. The slack notification gives you a link to the alert event in your Datadog account (click-1), and from the alert event, towards the bottom you'll find a series of links to other relevant places, one of those is "Related Logs" (click-2).

That brings you to the Log Explorer scoped to the relevant time period of the alert, and scoped to the tags of whatever it was that was alerted on (so presumably the logs you're looking for).

If you want to add a link of this sort as something you can configure in the alert message, that sounds like something you should reach out to support@datadoghq.com for to ask Datadog to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ log.link }}`

It's a builtin template variable.